# Rails 5 Bug (Segmentation fault)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, ruby-on-rails-5

Getting an error in the terminal running any rails command, for example 'rails test', after I modify a file in my project such as the model file 'users.rb' or the controller file 'users_controller.rb'. The bug is 'fixed' if I run 'spring stop' to restart the spring server. But it comes up every time I modify a file. Here is the initial message of the error/bug:

```
[sample_app (modeling-users)]$ time rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 43345
/Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000110
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

The error goes on for thousands of lines. Here is a small piece of the beginning of it:

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0072 p:---- s:0285 e:000284 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0071 p:---- s:0283 e:000282 CFUNC  :new
c:0070 p:0183 s:0278 e:000277 METHOD /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter
c:0069 p:0028 s:0271 e:000270 METHOD /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connec
c:0068 p:0027 s:0268 e:000267 METHOD /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connec
```

And here is the last few lines:

```
1696 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/testing/stream.rb
 1697 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators/testing/behaviour.rb
 1698 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb
 1699 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators/testing/assertions.rb
 1700 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/io/console.bundle
 1701 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb
 1702 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators/test_case.rb
 1703 /Users/AlfonsoGiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/testing/autorun.rb
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Basically every line is referring to '.rvm/gems/'  etc. Clearly it's a rvm/gems issue? I've run 'bundle update' and reinstalled my gems to no avail. If anything, suggestions on the cleanest way to uninstall/reinstall Ruby/Rails? Thinking that may be a solution but would want to do it properly. Thanks.

Comment: This could be a bug in Ruby if you're not running the latest version and re-installing it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried it with PostgreSQL/MySQL? Sqlite always creates problems down the line like this and incompatibilities with some AR features. And you'll probably not be using it on production, and this will cause another set of issues re. dev/prod parity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a defect with the sqlite3 gem.. See bug report here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12781 and https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12795

It does not appear there is a fix yet.. I'm having this issue as well, initially I was able to run brew update and then bundle update in a new terminal window which allowed me to call .connection on my models and get the console access again.. today this is still working but a very labourious process.

Comment: updated sqlite3 gem to 1.3.12: `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'`